# Disabling JavaScript on certain conditions like a media query

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I'm trying to disable this script to run at a certain screen size.

```
    <script>


    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 250,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();

</script>
```

I've tried wrapping the code with the following

```
   if($(window).width() > 1200) {
  // script here
  }
```

And

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 568){
         // script here
    } 
});
```

But none of them seems to work. Any recommendations?

Comment: `window.onload = init();` that is wrong

Comment: window.onload = function(){init();}

Comment: @neilsimp1 `window.onload = function(){init();};` can be written as just `window.onload = init;`

Comment: Thanks guys. But just to be clear, my initial script works just fine. It's just how I disable it to run below a certain breakpoint.

Comment: @rsp No way thanks I never knew you could do that!

Comment: I don't think the word `breakpoint` means what you think it means

Comment: How about renaming your init() to another name, then try again what you're doing? Maybe, javascript or jquery has a built in init().